# Can't stop Photos from restoring on my MacBook Pro

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app

Googled this but no satisfying answers. I have a MacBook Pro and just updated it to Catalina. My Photos have gone wacky. After several hours of "Updating Library", Photos is now stuck on "Restoring Library". I can't even access any pictures as all I get is a blank screen with "restoring photos" on it.

I have repaired the Photos Library so it is not that. I do have an iCloud account and assume this restoring thing has to do with iCloud. But turning off my iCloud drive is scary as it says all docs will be removed and I assume docs mean pictures. Unchecking Photos says iCloud Photos is currently updating and I will lose a few thousand plus pictures and videos from my Mac so that is scarier. The bottom line is I want Photos to stop "restoring". Driving me crazy.

Comment: Please attach a screenshot and provide information like how large your library is and what type of computer you have. I recommend against turning off iCloud options in the mean time.

Comment: Restoring a huge library can take very long indeed. Do you have a backup? If not, then immediately make one!